# How come my data does not log onto console reactjs and flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, fetch-api

I am trying to log my data into the console from my fetch function. I am currently able to log the response to the flask server but not on the react side. I have tried to include the headers in the fetch function however that does not seem to work. As I am still getting an error:

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

App.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
def api():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        email = request.form['email']
        occupation = request.form['occupation']
        print('Username: ' + username + ' Email: ' + email + ' occupation: ' + occupation) 
        print('Json ', (jsonify(username)))
        return {"username": username}
    else:
        return {"username": username}
```

App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Form from './components/Form'
import './App.css';


function App() {
  const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState ([{}])

  useEffect(()=> {
    fetch('/api',{
      headers: {
        method: 'GET',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(data => console.log(data))
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You'll likely find a logger approach significantly easier, and in some cases faster, than printing or console logging. Unfortunately, that may not answer your exact question, but wanted to leave a comment for thought, just in case.

Comment: could you please link me to more info about a logger approach?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your fetch is yielding a 500 error.  Thus, the response is something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML.....
```

the reason is you are sending a `GET` request, so it fails the `if request.method == 'POST':` test.  So, it tries to respond with `return {"username": username}`, but `username` is not defined in the `else` branch of the conditional.

Also, you might want to use:

```
return jsonify( {"username": username} )
```

to make sure you are sending an `application/json` mimetype response.

Comment: yes, I also have the else statement below, so shouldn't that pass the if request.method =='POST' and return the correct response?

Comment: No.  You are going to the `else:` branch of the conditional, but since `username` is not defined via that branch, you are crashing with a 500 response.

Comment: Ah, I see I just defined the username inside that branch which stopped the 500 response, however I am still getting the original error:

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Check your logs to find the error.  The `<` in position 0 is because it is returning an html response starting with `<!DOCTYPE...`.  Usually from an error.  Make sure you use jsonify to serve a JSON response.